# Is there a way to make saltstack behave like puppet for managed files?

Tags: puppet, salt-stack

Is there a way to make saltstack behave like puppet when it comes to managing config files. The task I want to do is to make `sshd_config` being managed by saltstack. If there are changes being made to the file, I want `salt master` to overwrite it by pushing in the master copy when the master detects that the managed config file is different or have been modified. Is this setup possible using saltstack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`file.managed`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html) which may look like that:

```
/etc/http/conf/http.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://apache/http.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
```

Salt will transfer this file over to a minion whenever you apply this state to a minion.

Monitoring the file from the master can be achieved, but it is more complex to do so. You can make use of [the reactor system](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/) of salt and write a small python program on the minion, which watches the file and fires an [custom event](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/event/custom.html) to the salt event bus in case of changes. Inside of the reactor you can listen on those custom events and perform the desired state on the minion.

Notice that this just a custom solution if you need to react more or less just in time (if you really want to react in time, all this should be done inside of the minion, without the reactor system).

Please notice that a more common approach in salt looks like that: you schedule `highstates` for minions in your favorite interval and make sure, they have your desired state each `x` hours.

Comment: I want salt master to monitor the file and transfer the file whenever the file at minion changes.

Comment: i've updated the answer regarding your desired behaviour.